# Tablesorter Bootstrap theme not showing unsorted icon in header

Tags: tablesorter

The unsorted icons are not showing up.  Other themes do not work, either.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I have provided my code below.

The icons only show up for the columns that I have set to sort in sortList.

I am unclear when I need to add a theme to widgets (e.g., widgets: ['uitheme'}) and when to use theme (e.g., theme: "bootstrap").

Do I need to include all of the css files that I have?

Is more needed in headerTemplate, particularly for bootstrap?

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.5/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js"></script>
</head>


<script>  

$(function() { 

// call the tablesorter plugin 
$("table").tablesorter({ 
theme: "bootstrap",
// sort on the first column and in ascending order PRIOR TO the sort on the     selected column
// sort [column,asc=1 or desc=0] 
sortList: [[1,0]],
// hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize  the change
widthFixed : false,

headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
// initialize zebra striping and filter widgets 
widgets: ['uitheme','zebra', 'filter','output'],

//headers: { 
//0: {sorter: 'checkbox', filter:true},
//1: {sorter: 'inputs',filter:true}
//},

widgetOptions : { 

// css class applied to the table row containing the filters & the inputs within that row 
filter_cssFilter : 'tablesorter-filter', 

// filter widget: If there are child rows in the table (rows with class name from "cssChildRow" option) 
// and this option is true and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make that row 
// visible; default is false 
filter_childRows : false, 

// Set this option to true to use the filter to find text from the start of the column 
// So typing in "a" will find "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false 
filter_startsWith : false,
// Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching; This option prevents searching for
// every character while typing and should make searching large tables faster.
filter_searchDelay : 100,

 // if true, search column content while the user types (with a delay)
filter_liveSearch : true

}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`theme.bootstrap.css` file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/css/theme.bootstrap.css) appears to be missing. It contains the unsorted arrow definition.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.5/css/theme.bootstrap.min.css" >
```

Comment: I'm unclear if I want to use another theme if I need to add a different css, theme: x, and widgets: 'uitheme'.  I'm not understanding all that is required of a different them.

Comment: the `uitheme` widget was initially created to change the class names applied to headers & sort icons when a column was sorted. It was needed for jQuery UI, then Bootstrap. It isn't as essential as it once was because most of the class names are now part of the options, but it does make it easier to switch between themes. So use the `uitheme` widget only for jQuery UI & Bootstrap. Everything else works fine without it.